# Does the Soul Knife's blade skill Mind Blade Finesse require the Weapon Finesse feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

Does the Soul Knife's blade skill Mind Blade Finesse require the Weapon Finesse feat?

> Mind Blade Finesse
> Mind Blade Finesse: The benefits of the Weapon Finesse feat apply to the mind blade even when it is in forms that cannot normally be the subject of Weapon Finesse (including two-handed forms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No, but also yes

[Mind Blade Finesse](https://libraryofmetzofitz.fandom.com/wiki/Blade_Skills) states:

> Mind Blade Finesse: The benefits of the Weapon Finesse feat apply to the mind blade even when it is in forms that cannot normally be the subject of Weapon Finesse (including two-handed forms).

Compare this to Flurry of Fists:

> Flurry of Fists: When making unarmed attacks and making a full attack, the soulknife can make one additional attack at her highest attack bonus, but all attacks in the full attack suffer a -2 penalty to the attack roll. This extra attack does not stack with abilities that grant additional attacks, such as Two-Weapon Fighting, Flurry of Blows, or other such effects. **The soulknife must have the Improved Unarmed Strike feat in order to select this blade skill.**

Since Mind Blade Finesse does not have that line about requiring weapon finesse in order to take it, you can take it without having the feat.

Note: In order to receive the effects of weapon finesse, you still need to have taken the feat, as all Mind Blade Finesse does is allow you to apply its effects to your weapons.

Comment: So no, but also yes.

Comment: @RevanantBacon exactly

Comment: So technically what weapon should I choose with the Weapon Finesse feat in order to utilize the Blade Skill Mind Blade Finesse, shouldn't it be the Soul Knife's Mind Blades they are capable of making in general or more specific like the Light Weapon variant of the Soul Knife's Mind Blade?

Comment: What? You don't choose a weapon when you take weapon finesse, it applies to every weapon that qualifies.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Note that you **do not need** Mind Blade Finesse **unless** you want to use a mind blade form that is not compatible with Weapon Finesse. If you want to use Dexterity with a mind blade in the form of a short sword, you only need Weapon Finesse. But if you want a mind blade in the shape of a greatsword and use Weapon Finesse with *that*, **then** you need to have Mind Blade Finesse as well as Weapon Finesse. (It may be worth including this point in your answer, willuwontu.)